# Why can't change the default program to open an extension in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-association

I mistakenly assign Office Outlook to open my .eml files in Windows 7. But, as Outlook do not open such files, I downloaded Live Mail, but now I can not assign it to open this kind of file by default.

I've tried running Explorer as Administrator, not to avail.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, pretty lame having to download a program just to change the setting.

Comment: Wow, I never noticed that the *File Types* tab of *Folder Options* is gone. Populating the dialog is slow and I use `.reg` file to manage file-types, so I never use it, but obviously a lot of [people relied on it](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistadesktopui/thread/0ee43527-8d6e-4da3-80dc-80058215d7e6) and have to resort to [other methods](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-do-i-change-file-extension-associations-in-windows-vista/6172036) now. For the record, the box is grey sometimes depending on the extension and context (it’s *always* greyed for executable types).

Comment: Related: [I can't set a program as the default to open a filetype with in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/655600/358766)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Windows Vista and Windows 7's file type management facilities are half-baked at best. I never understood why Microsoft crippled that part of the OS when they released Vista. They added limitations that make absolutely no sense.

You might want to try to use alternatives listed in my previous question on the matter:

> [What program do you use to edit file associations in Vista and Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/22933/what-program-do-you-use-to-edit-file-associations-in-vista-and-windows-7)

The program that stood out was [**Default Programs Editor**](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) which is free and will allow you do pretty much whatever you wish to do.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is amazing: Using "Default program Settings" gives me the error "The default programs association for some extensions could not be saved due to a registry permissions issue. This could be a result of a previous tweaks by other programs to your settings" (doh!)

Comment: Using "File type settings" and trying to delete the extension crash the program (I think due to permissions also)

Comment: Note that I'm running the program as Administrator

Comment: Yahoo!! Using "File type settings" and editing the "Open" context menu solved the problem!!

Comment: I guess the permissions in the registry were messed up majorly.

Comment: Just for the posterity: the correct command for open the eml file directly is <code>"C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Mail\wlmail.exe" /eml:%1</code>

Comment: The site is down.  The program can be downloaded from here: [defaultprogramseditor.com - download (via archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20141217000328/http://defaultprogramseditor.com/).  It works.  It appears to have been written by this guy: [Factor Mystic (Facebook)](https://www.facebook.com/factor.mystic)

Answer (score 3):

My answer relates to a similar, but not the same, problem, where I can't associate a file extension with a program with the same name of a deleted program previously used for this extension, when the new program is located in a different path.  Nonetheless, this should be relevant to your case.

As others have noted, broken registry entries explain this behavior.  I used [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to get rid of the erroneous entry after I tried and failed to get rid of it by myself.  This seems to happen when a program used to open a specific file type is deleted and you try to associate this file type with another program with the same name installed elsewhere.  When this happens, Windows gets confused about the program used to open it, and the system can't associate the file extension with the new program.

You may want to look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/282539/what-is-the-best-option-for-windows-registry-clean/282553#282553) for more information and some cautions on registry cleaners including CCleaner.

Answer (score 2):

To change an extension to not be opened by *any* program:

1. Create a text file with a line of gibberish in it.
2. Save to your desktop with the `.txt` extension.
3. In Control Panel, go to the extension for which you want to remove the default association.
4. Assign the above text file to be the default program for that extension.
5. Close Control Panel.
6. Go back to the text file and delete it.

The extension that was associated with this text file in step 4 will now show it is associated with an "unknown" program.

Answer (score 1):

you may use the **File Type Doctor** which is part of the [**Creative Element Power Tools**](http://www.creativelement.com/powertools/) to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but had the same problem and this simple tool fixed it for me. Simply select the extension and click on "Delete file type". After that, the option was no longer greyed out.
http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/231/1/An-Utility-to-Unassociate-File-Types-in-Windows-7-and-Vista.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the registry entry may be botched, another way to fix this might be to run a registry cleaner (I used Eusing Free Registry Cleaner) that will detect an invalid entry and delete it. Afterwards, you can try again to associate the extension the normal way. This worked for me, after I had switched from a portable to a system installation, and the registry still pointed to the portable installation.

Comment: I use CCleaner's registry cleaner, and this works as well.  However, see http://superuser.com/questions/282539/what-is-the-best-option-for-windows-registry-clean/282553#282553 for some cautions.

Answer (score 0):

Is "NoFileAssociate" set to 0?

From [KB555076](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/555076):

1. Go to "Start" -> "Run".
2. Write "Regedit" and press on "Enter" button.
3. Navigate to:
       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer
4. In the right side of the screen double click on "NoFileAssociate".
5. Change the value of  "NoFileAssociate" from 1 to 0.
6. Close "Regedit".
7. Reboot the server.

Comment: There is no key, and adding it makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

Let me share a related experience with my Win7 PC. My PC had two email clients installed Lotus notes and Outlook 2013. Had set outlook as the default to open all email related extensions such as .eml, .msg, .vcf, .vcs etc. However .eml files were not opening when i double clicked on a file with .eml extension. Had to use the "open with" option to open such files in outlook.
Hence i went to control panel - "Set default programs" - "Outlook"- "choose defaults for this program"- and checked the .eml option. However on going back the check box for .eml files had cleared itself.

Solution: Found the below reg key 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.eml]
Deleted the .eml key. Double clicked the .eml file and it opened in outlook , also the  .eml option got checked in "Set default programs" for outlook in control panel.