# How can I create a shell context menu item that takes multiple files as arguments?

Tags: windows-7, windows, context-menu

Creating a Windows Shell context menu item that takes a single file as an argument is easy.  See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/392212/how-can-i-add-a-program-to-the-context-menu-of-all-files) for an example.

However, how do you create a context menu item that takes multiple files as arguments?  Say, for a diff-merge tool (in my case P4Merge), although the same technique would no doubt be applicable for other applications as well.

I've installed P4Merge but it does not add an item to the context menu automatically so I will have to do it manually.

When I tried using:

```
"C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe" %1 %2
```

as the command line I got an error:

> Errors: At least two files are needed.  Cannot open only one file.  P4Merge needs 0, 2, or 3 files.

When I tried using:

```
"C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe" %0 %1
```

as the command line it opened two instances of P4Merge, one for each file.

It appears the correct file names are being passed through to %0 and %1 but a different instance of the P4Merge application is being executed for each one.

I currently have SourceGear's DiffMerge tool which has an item on the Shell context menu and that works beautifully, as I am able to select two files and use the context menu item to run a diff on them.  I've trying searching the registry to see what arguments DiffMerge uses but I could not find a DiffMerge commandline that included arguments.

Comment: As you found out, there is no way to do what you want with a simple registry hack. There is only %1 because the extension only applies to one object and is executed separately for multiple objects. It requires programming a full-on shell-extension. There are however some programs/shell-extensions that let you do some more advanced context-menu stuff than a registry hack will allow. (The only one I can remember is [MMM](http://hace-software.com/mmm.shtml).) Unfortunately, I think they tend to be limited to letting you make submenus rather than allow for multiple objects to be dropped.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can also try adding the program to the SendTo menu.

Comment: Yup, that works nicely.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Here are [instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/) for how to add an application to the SendTo menu in Windows 7.  There was no need to add any command-line parameters, just dropped the application shortcut into the %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo folder.  Back in Windows Explorer, selecting two files then right-clicking and selecting Send To > P4Merge performed a diff on the selected files.

Answer (score 7):

Browsing for the answer it seems that there is no simple fix and that a shell extension is needed.  Looking again at the registry entries for DiffMerge, it appears to use a shell extension: DiffMergeShellExtension64.dll.  If P4Merge does not have such a shell extension then it looks like the only way I could get it working correctly in the Windows Explorer context menu would be to write one myself.

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens) series in Code Project is a useful guide to writing shell extensions.  Part II of the series is about writing an extension that handles multiple files at once (exactly what I need).

Warning: The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions uses C and COM, ATL (Active Template Library) and MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes).  So writing a shell extension, if you're not familiar with those technologies, is going to be a long and potentially difficult process; it's definitely not something you can do in an hour.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with my program [context-menu-launcher (singleinstance)](https://github.com/zenden2k/context-menu-launcher):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.txt\Shell\p4merge]
"MultiSelectModel"="Player"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.txt\Shell\p4merge\Command]
@="\"d:\\singleinstance.exe\" %1 \"C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge.exe\" $files --si-timeout 400"
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks.  Is there any way to associate the singleinstance application with any file type, without adding it to the file associations for each file type individually?  For example, I currently use DiffMerge for comparing things like XML files, SQL scripts, config files, *.cs files, .gitignore files, plus others.

Answer (score 0):

### SUMMARY

1. In Registry put the target program as **Context Menu Create File.exe** which writes **reg.txt** file.
2. In your main program loop every 1 second to check if **reg.txt** exists. If it exists, kill the **Context Menu Create File.exe** and delete the **reg.txt** file. Then copy the selected file paths and manipulate with them.
3. If your program loops to check for **reg.txt**, then you need to start the program before executing context menu either on startup or manually.

> I did this with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com).
>
> These 2 AutoHotkey scripts below allow you to add a `P4 Merge Compare` context menu item in Windows Explorer to open multiple selected files.
>
> You can leave all variable values as they are, but if you want to change the `contextMenu` value and `program` name then see **3.1.**

### INSTRUCTIONS:

Create 2 files in the same directory:

1. Create 1st program **Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk**

   1. `RunAsAdmin` Label ensures that the script runs as admin (fixes adding Registry values).

      1. The `If (!A_IsAdmin)` checks if current user is **NOT** admin, A_IsAdmin is a built in AutoHotkey variable that returns 1 if user is admin, 0 otherwise.
      2. `Run, \*RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"` ***RunAs** parameter runs the script as admin, **"%A_ScriptFullPath%"** gets the full path of the current executing script.
      3. `ExitApp` exits the current script instance running without admin privileges.
      4. Because the `Run` command runs the script again with admin privileges it will skip the `IF` condition and continue executing code below.
   2. `ContextMenuCreateFile:`  Label creates a **Context Menu Create File.exe** which creates a file **reg.txt** and exits **Context Menu Create File.exe** after it has written the file **reg.txt**. Make sure you specify where your `Ahk2Exe.exe` path is in the `RunWait` command.
   3. `Add To Context Menu:`  Label adds the Registry entry which runs **Context Menu Create File.exe**.

      1. Set the `contextMenu` variable to what needs to be displayed in the Context Menu. (The `program` name is set to `contextMenu`)
      2. Set the `regPath` to your desired Registry path.
      3. When it executes the `MsgBox`, check if the command is added to the Registry in the address bar.
   4. `CreateStartupShortcut:` Label creates the shortcut of the main program **P4 Merge Compare.exe** in Startup folder.

### Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk

```
; =============Recommended Settings=============
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#Warn
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
DetectHiddenWindows Off
DetectHiddenText On
#WinActivateForce
#NoTrayIcon
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
; =============Recommended Settings=============

AddToContextMenuAndCreateStartupShortcut:
RunAsAdmin:  ; =============RunAsAdmin=============
If (!A_IsAdmin)  ; IF NOT Admin
{
    Run, *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Run script as admin
    ExitApp  ; Exit the current instance running without admin privileges
}
ContextMenuCreateFile:  ; =============ContextMenuCreateFile=============
contextMenuCreateFileAhk := 
(LTrim
"#NoEnv
#NoTrayIcon
#SingleInstance Force
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetBatchLines -1

ContextMenuCreateFile:
FileDelete, reg.txt
FileAppend, , reg.txt
ExitApp
Return"
)  ; contextMenuCreateFileAhk
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.exe  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.exe
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.ahk
FileAppend, %contextMenuCreateFileAhk%, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; MAKE Context Menu Create File.ahk
RunWait, C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Compiler\Ahk2Exe.exe /in "Context Menu Create File.ahk" /out "Context Menu Create File.exe"  ; Convert AHK to EXE
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.ahk
AddToContextMenu:  ; =============AddToContextMenu=============
path := ""  ; path
program := "Context Menu Create File"  ; program
contextMenu := "P4 Merge Compare"  ; contextMenu
regPath := "HKCR\*\shell"  ; regPath
StringReplace, regKey, contextMenu, %A_Space%, , A  ; regKey
regKey := 0 regKey  ; regKey
Loop, Files, %program%.exe, F  ; Find Program.exe In Current Dir
{
    path := A_LoopFileLongPath  ; Set Program Path
}
cmd := 
(LTrim
"reg add """ regPath "\" regKey """ /ve /t REG_SZ /d """ contextMenu """ /f
reg add """ regPath "\" regKey "\command"" /ve /t REG_SZ /d ""\""" path "\""`"" /f"
)  ; Registry
FileDelete, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; CREATE Add To Context Menu.bat
FileAppend, %cmd%, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; CREATE Add To Context Menu.bat
RunWait, Add To Context Menu.bat, , Hide  ; RUN Add To Context Menu.bat (*RunAs ADMIN)
FileDelete, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; DEL Add To Context Menu.bat
Run, regedit  ; regedit
WinWait, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; Registry
Sleep, 333
ControlSetText, Edit1, %regPath%\%regKey%\command, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlFocus, Edit1, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, Edit1, {Enter}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, SysListView321, {Control Down}{NumpadAdd}{Control Up}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, SysListView321, {F5}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
MsgBox, 262192, CHECK, Check If Added %contextMenu% To Registry  ; CHECK
CreateStartupShortcut:  ; =============CreateStartupShortcut=============
path := ""  ; path
program := contextMenu  ; program
Loop, Files, %program%.exe, F  ; Find Program.exe In Current Dir
{
    path := A_LoopFileLongPath  ; Set Program Path
}
FileCreateShortcut, %path%, %A_Startup%\%program%.lnk  ; Create Startup Shortcut
Run, %A_Startup%, , Max  ; Check If Shortcut Created
Run, "%program%.exe"  ; Run Program
MsgBox, 262144, CHECK, Check If Shortcut Created  ; CHECK
ExitApp  ; ExitApp
Return
```

2. Create 2nd program **P4 Merge Compare.ahk** which is the main program.

   1. Here a `Loop` is created and checks every 1 second if **reg.txt** exists.
   2. `IfExist, reg.txt` it kills the **Context Menu Create File.exe** and deletes the **reg.txt**.
   3. Then it activates explorer.exe window and copies all selected file paths to **CLIPBOARD**.
   4. `If CLIPBOARD contains .,\` to make sure **CLIPBOARD** contains path **"\"** with extension **"."**.
   5. The list of selected files is saved in `selectedFiles` variable.
   6. The Loop below `p4Params := ""` loops through selected files, gets the `filePath`s.
   7. Then the `filePath` is concatenated to `p4Params`.
   8. `StringTrimRight` removes the last space from `p4Params` string.
   9. Then `Run, C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe %p4Params%` is executed with `%p4Params%` (list of selected files).

### P4 Merge Compare.ahk

```
; =============Recommended Settings=============
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#Warn
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
DetectHiddenWindows Off
DetectHiddenText On
#WinActivateForce
#NoTrayIcon
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
; =============Recommended Settings=============

P4MergeCompare:
Loop  ; Loop Start
{
    Sleep, 1000  ; Fix High CPU
    IfExist, reg.txt  ; IF reg.txt EXIST
    {
        RunWait, cmd /c taskkill /im "Context Menu Create File.exe" /f, , Hide  ; Fix Opening 2 Compose Windows
        FileDelete, reg.txt  ; DEL reg.txt
        WinActivate, ahk_class CabinetWClass ahk_exe explorer.exe  ; Explorer
        CLIPBOARD := ""  ; Clear Clipboard
        Send, {Control Down}{c}{Control Up}  ; Copy File Paths
        ClipWait, 0  ; Clip Wait
        If CLIPBOARD contains .,\  ; IF CLIPBOARD contains .,\
        {
            selectedFiles := CLIPBOARD  ; selectedFiles
            p4Params := ""  ; p4Params
            Loop, Parse, selectedFiles, `n, `r  ; Loop Start selectedFiles
            {
                filePath := """" A_LoopField """"  ; filePath
                p4Params .= filePath . " "  ; p4Params .= %filePath%,
            }
            StringTrimRight, p4Params, p4Params, 1  ; Remove Last Space
            Run, C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe %p4Params%  ; Open Files In P4Merge
        }
    }
}
Return
```

3. Convert both **Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk** and **P4 Merge Compare.ahk** to **EXE** files in the same directory using **Ahk2Exe.exe** --> (find in Start Menu, just browse file and hit convert)
4. Execute the **`Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.exe`**
5. Select files, right click and the **P4 Merge Compare** context menu item should appear.