# Run Single Instance of CMD via Registry for Multiple Files?

Tags: windows, batch, windows-registry

I have written a script to convert images with [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex). I use `%*` in the command inside the script to handle however many files I pass to it by directly dragging multiple files onto it directly. It opens and handles all files in a single instance if I do it this way. I want to integrate this command into my context menu, I have done this but I cannot use `%*` for the command in the registry so I am using `%1`. If I use this, it will handle all files selected, but a separate instance is opened for each file passed to the script. How can I structure the command in the registry to handle all files passed to it in a single instance? I have tried multiple other wildcards for the command but none have had the desired effect.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a shell context menu item that takes multiple files as arguments?](https://superuser.com/questions/425940/how-can-i-create-a-shell-context-menu-item-that-takes-multiple-files-as-argument)

Comment: The question is essentially the same but unfortunately the solutions provided there do not tackle this in an amicable way or at all @DrMoishePippik.

Comment: `but I cannot use %* for the command in the registry` people use `"%1" %*` in the file association all the time without problem: [Associate a File Type with a Specific Program](https://superuser.com/a/794467/241386), [Best way to get file type association in Windows 10 from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60972216/995714)