# Adding key to registry

Tags: windows, batch, windows-registry

I would like to create a batch file, that will add registry key, not manually, but full automaticly by .BAT file. [This link](https://superuser.com/questions/392212/how-can-i-add-a-program-to-the-context-menu-of-all-files) goes about adding everything but not the key. [This link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516/en-us) shows how to add everything, and how to add key manually, but it requires user interference, which I am trying to avoid.

Is there possibility to add KEY (non REG_*) to "folder?" in registry by one simple batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a command prompt type `REG /?` and you will see the functionality available in your batch file.
`REG ADD /?` will give you more info on actually adding the key.  If you're planning on running this from SCCM, you may need to specify 32/64 bit registry as it may cause some errors.

Actual Examples of REG ADD:

```
REG ADD HKLM\Software\MyCo /v Data /t REG_BINARY /d fe340ead
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742162(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Do you know maybe the way. How to modify the default file of specific key (folder)?

Comment: @RikTelner: To change the default value, specify it as `/v ""` or `/ve`. This is mentioned in `reg add /?`.