# how to add reg key from batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file named `pp.bat` and converted to pp.exe using bat2exe tool. It works. 
I want to add this key to my batch file :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"p"="c:\\pp.exe"
```

so that it runs when windows starts. The batch code of my file is:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /a VAR=0 
:HOME 
SET /a VAR=VAR+1  
IF %VAR%==3 goto :End  
start www.google.com 
goto :HOME 
:END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding key to registry](http://superuser.com/questions/622394/adding-key-to-registry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `regedit` tool can be run from the command-line as detailed in *[How to add, modify, or delete registry subkeys and values by using a .reg file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516)* :

> to silently run the `.reg` file (with the `/s` switch) from a login script batch file, use the following syntax:

`regedit.exe /s`*path of .reg file*

You can also (as noted in *[Adding key to registry](https://superuser.com/questions/622394/adding-key-to-registry)*) use [`reg add`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742162.aspx) to add a key.  That answer gives (without clues regarding syntax, etc), this example:

```
REG ADD HKLM\Software\MyCo /v Data /t REG_BINARY /d fe340ead
```

making it not useful.  If it had been useful, this would be a duplicate.

From the documentation, and matching it to *your* key, you might use this command:

```
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v "p" /t REG_SZ /d "c:\\pp.exe"
```

That is,

- using `reg add`,
- specify  as `"HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"`,
- specify the name of the registry key as `"p"`,
- specify the type as `REG_SZ` ([a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), and
- specify the data (key's value) as `"c:\\pp.exe"`

The `"\\"` in your key's value looks odd.  You might want to check that.

Comment: It worked and you are right about "\\" its a "\" . Thx @ Thomas Dickey

Comment: Yes definitely "accepted"