# Windows 7: Trigger a scan from file browser?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, scanner

I'm trying to find the shortest path between a file upload input on a web page and scanning a document. My current workflow is to scan a document into a folder on the computer, then upload the file from the computer using the upload file dialog.

Is there any way to *manually* add a scanner in the default file browser dialog such that when I click on a "select file to upload" button on the web, I can select the scanner and initiate a scan using the file browser dialog?

*Note: I am not trying to add this option dynamically from the web page. I am using the computer attached to the scanner, and I want to be able to initiate scans from file inputs while browsing the web.*

*A file upload link in Internet Explorer:*

[image: file upload button]

*Consequent file browsing dialogue:*

[image: file browser dialog]

*An imaginary possible addition to the file browsing dialogue:*

[image: new file browser option]

Comment: Letting a webpage control the computer like that would probably be something of a security hole, so I don't think you can do it. If you own the web page and are on the same network, you could tell the users to place the scanned file in a certain folder, and then write a script to copy the files over automatically.

Comment: @David I think you misunderstood what I'm trying to do. I am _not_ trying to dynamically add this option from the web page. I _am_ trying to add this option _manually_ as an admin user on Windows so that it shows up when I am uploading files to any webpage.

Comment: That should be possible then. You might be able to add a context entry to all folders to pull up your scanner. http://superuser.com/questions/392212/how-can-i-add-a-program-to-the-context-menu-of-all-files