# How to order files in explorer by file extension (not type)

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is it possible to make windows explorer order the files view in a folder by the file extensions (e.g. .jpg, .png, .gif and so on)?

In most cases it is sufficient for me to order by file type, but I have some associations that read the same but mean different extensions.

I'm using Windows 7. There is a freeware utility called CPExt wich adds a new selectable column to windows explorer that shows the file extension. Thus, you can order the view by this new column. That's exactly what I am searching for for windows 7. That tool is only available for windows versions up to XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly not the answer you wanted, but...Microsoft removed the functionality to allow explorer addons to add columns - it was removed in Vista and is not in Windows 7 either. That's why the CPExt extension only works up to Windows XP.

See the following article for an explanation:

> http://xpwasmyidea.blogspot.com/2009/10/evil-conspiracy-behind-customizable.html

An alternative would be to use an Explorer replacement - [Explorer++](http://www.explorerplusplus.com) is an open source piece of software that you can use instead of explorer (or as a standalone app, which may suit your needs). Explorer++ allows you to select File Extension as a column and then you can sort by extension.

Comment: Vista and higher have a new shell extension API that can still do this - it's called Property Handlers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe stating the obvious here, but you could change the description of the file type extension. E.g. by adding the file type extension to the description between parentheses.

See [What program do you use to edit file associations in Vista and Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/22933) for possibilities doing so in Windows 7.