# Why does Windows append .php to my php files but not other ones

Tags: windows, php, file-extension

I have many different types of files in a folder - .php, .css, .htm, .js, .docx, .xls, etc.

The only file type that Windows (viewed from Windows Explorer) actually shows the extension are the .php files.

Why is this?

Answer (score 20):

Two things are most likely on your system for this to happen:

1. The option **Hide extensions for known file types** is checked.
2. You haven't registered the PHP filetype to your system and thus is an unrecognised file format.

These combined will show **.php** file extensions while other documents are hidden.

You can change this when you open a folder and go to: **Tools > Options > View**

There you'll see the option to uncheck **Hide extensions for known file types**. Do so and save.

If you want to hide the PHP file extensions, leave the extensions option hidden and just [register the filetype](https://superuser.com/questions/22933/what-program-do-you-use-to-edit-file-associations-in-vista-and-windows-7).

Comment: It is a library computer.  For what ever reason I guess Windows automatically has those filetypes registered but not PHP.  That's PHP discrimination!

Comment: Windows doesn't handle PHP files by default. Usually only gets added if you're doing some web dev. Looks like you won't be able to configure the system settings if the computer is locked down. @chr

Answer (score 3):

Look at one of the PHP file properties from explorer.
Maybe its called `filename.php.php` !!

You seem to have your filename extensions visibility set to [hidden](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Show-or-hide-file-name-extensions).
But, that does not work when you have the extension two times.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change the properties of folders. By default windows hides extensions of known files.

Under Control Panel -> Folder option -> View tab, uncheck the "Hide extensions for known file types" box