# Windows 7 - right click menu commands for file types

Tags: windows-7, shell, windows-registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What program do you use to edit file associations in Vista and Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/22933/what-program-do-you-use-to-edit-file-associations-in-vista-and-windows-7)

it was fairly easy to setup addition right click commands in windows XP.

for example you could add a handler for .sql file types that would "execute on dev" automatically running the file against SQLCMD.EXE.

this functionality appears to be lost in windows 7. the only solutions i've seen around is direct registry edits. and most of them just add a shell command that is not filtered by file type..

what's a good utility / way to accomplish this?

UPDATE

working with [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-add-context-menu-commands-for-file-types/883b8423-8ac2-43bc-b0ae-3ac2be8e89e7) solution of creating a .reg file.. so far unsuccessfully (don't see the new item in .sql context menu)

Comment: This might be a relevant question for you: http://superuser.com/questions/22933/what-program-do-you-use-to-edit-file-associations-in-vista-and-windows-7